# Configuring an Elastic Job in Azure to run at a specific time in a specific Time Zone rather than UTC

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

We use Elastic Jobs to run overnight housekeeping scripts. These scripts need to run at a specific time during the night.

That's where this pesky thing called Daylight Saving, Summer Time or whatever it's called in your part of the world throws a minor spanner in the works.

To configure a job to start at a certain time we run

```
EXEC jobs.sp_update_job <etcera>, @schedule_start_time=<datetime in UTC>
```

The problem is that that will only work for part of the year. For example, here in Ireland we are currently on BST, i.e. UTC+1, so if I want to run this job at 06:00 every morning we would have to call the above with the @schedule_start_time parameter set to 05:00

This means that if we want to keep running this job all year round at 06:00 we need to run the sp_update_job statement at the time the clocks change. Which is not a big deal but a pain in the proverbial all the same.

So my question is:

**Is there a way to call sp_update_job with a @schedule_start_time parameter that is interpreted as a local time so that it automatically adjusts when Daylight Savings starts or finishes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Elastic Jobs use UTC time zone for scheduling and do not automatically adjust for daylight savings. Therefore, as you already mentioned, you need to manually update the @schedule_start_time parameter of the sp_update_job procedure when the clocks change.

However, you have an alternative Azure service named [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/overview) that support time zones and adjust to daylight saving based on the schedule's time zone. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules#create-a-new-schedule-with-powershell) you will find more details.

```
$TimeZone = ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local).Id
New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName "ContosoAutomation" -Name "Schedule01" -StartTime "23:00" -OneTime -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -TimeZone $TimeZone
```